# mongodb - wiredtiger memory usage growing

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

We moved over to wiredtiger and have seen memory usage creep up, with mongodb using 90% of the memory on the system. It seems to be slowly creaping up. Before wiredtiger when we used mmap on mongo 2.x memory would sit at 8%.

I am worried about the operating system killing the process. Is this normal behaviour?

db.serverStatus() - https://gist.github.com/henryoswald/8ff9cf917e63c2e983dd

Comment: Make sure you're aware of https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20306

Answer (score 3):

There is a big difference between mmap and WiredTiger in the way they use memory.

While mmap actually uses memory mapping, so that the database cache is actually accounted as cache in the OS.

While WiredTiger uses memory pool defined at the application start. [see docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#prod-notes-ram)

Depending on the amount of memory in your system, by default it should use either 1GB or half the system RAM for WiredTiger pool. (that would explain jump from 8 % to 58 % or so)

But it should not be "slowly creeping to 90 %". That would deserve further investigation. But for that, we'd need to see more info. Like `db.serverStatus()`, or the method you use to find memory usage, or whatever else you can find and share about that server instance.

Comment: thanks for your help I have added my db.serverStatus() to the question.

Comment: @henry.oswald maybe you should update to 3.0.4 per [this bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6826)

Comment: Thanks I will try it, so I know what lead you to thinking that might be the cause?

Comment: Well, your setup serverStatus says you have ~8GB reserved for WT cache. It is currently using less. You say your memory usage is slowly growing. All signs of memory leak. And you do quite a lot of connections (almost 10million in 20 days). If every connection leaked 512B structure (haven't checked the size), it's 5GB. Still it is a guess though. But probably easier to try, than wasting time trying to prove it.